# JSR-303 Annotation on Spring Bean Properties

Tags: java, spring, bean-validation

Is there a straightforward way to have Spring beans validated **on context startup** using JSR-303 annotations? I've inherited some classes that represent configuration as JSR-303-annotated POJOs. These are passed all around an object hierarchy, so I'm kinda stuck using them.

I could imagine defining beans setting the properties of such a class, and then having a JSR-303 validator run on context startup that would ensure all values are set correctly.

Note that I'm *not* asking about validation of bound form submissions in Spring MVC.

Comment: post some code so we can help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is no. Although not originally mentioned in JSR-303 it is typically used for MVC data binding and validation. I would try the following.

Since you have JSR-303 annotations, so configure a [JSR-303 validator in Spring context](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#validation-beanvalidation-spring). In this case, it will be a `LocalValidatorFactoryBean` that bootstraps a standard JSR-303 validation mechanism. Note that you still need to have a vendor/implementor of JSR-303 available in your class path (e.g. Hibernate Validator).

Implement an instance of [`ApplicationContextListener<ContextStartedEvent>`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationListener.html) to receive the event when the application context is started and ready. Also, allow the bean to receive an instance of `LocalValidatorFactoryBean`:

```
public class GenericApplicationValidator implements ApplicationListener<ContextStartedEvent> {

  private ValidatorFactoryBean validatorFactoryBean;

  public void onApplicationEvent(ContextStartedEvent e) {
    // Refer to next step
  }

  public void setValidatorFactoryBean(ValidatorFactoryBean vfb) {
    this.validatorFactoryBean = vfb;
  }
}
```

In the method `onApplicationEvent(ContextStartedEvent e)`:

1. Fetch the instance of application context.
2. Through the application context, find all the beans you need to validate.
3. You have access to `validatorFactoryBean.getValidator()`
4. Iterate over all the beans, use the validator and validate the bean.

Remember that I have not had an experience on doing this. But it looks to me it can be one way to get close to achieve what you need.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do this validation just after context initialization, you could do something like:

```
@Component
public class MyValidator ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {

    @Autowired private ListableBeanFactory bf;
    @Autowired private Validator validator;


    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
        for (String name : bf.getBeanDefinitionNames()) {
            Object bean = bf.getBean(name);
            validator.validate(bean);
        }
    }
}
```

But I haven't tested it.